# Effective way to make NavMeshAgents jump/climb obstacles in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navmesh

So I'm working on a zombie game and I want my zombies to be able to climb/jump over certain obstacles around the map. I know that I can create nav mesh links to achieve this but when doing it it feels forced as the zombies will go to the link to connect the climb/jump instead of just going over the obstacle. I am having trouble in my research finding an effective way to do this.

Basically here is what I want to achieve:

1.) When a zombie reaches a certain obstacle (fence, car, crate, etc.) that is climbable, instead of running around the obstacle to get to the player I want the zombie to climb or jump over the obstacle.

2.) When the player climbs on top of an obstacle I want the zombies to also be able to climb on the obstacle to be able to attack the player.

Does anyone have suggestions on effective ways to go about this or possible methods I could further research? From the hours I've spent researching this I'm not having any luck finding something that goes with what I want to achieve.